# Java method not overloaded

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have something like:

A.java:

```
package project;
public class A {
    protected void method(A param){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

B.java:

```
package project.sub;
import project.A;
public class B extends A {
    protected void method(B param){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

C.java:

```
package project;
import project.sub.B;
public class C extends B {
    // …/…
}
```

Test.java:

```
package project;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c1 = new C(), c2 = new C();
        c1.method(c2); // prints "A"
    }
}
```

Now when I call `method` on an instance of `C`, I expected to see "B", but it's "A" that is printed.

`method` can't be overridden, since it's not the same signature. How can I make sure that it's the `B` implementation that is called.

**EDIT:** I know that it should print "B". So my question can also be: what could be the reasons that it's not.

**EDIT2:** if I implement `method` on `C`, it's working as it should. I still don't get why.

```
public class C extends B {
    public void method(C param) {
        super.method(param);
    }
}
```

**EDIT3:** Found it! `A` and `C` are in the same package, `B` is not.

**EDIT4:** Updated example to make a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This code should print "B", and that's what it prints for me. `method(B param)` is more specific than `method(A param)`, which is why the compiler prefers that method when you pass an argument of type C.

Comment: Be aware that it can still print "A" if you do "c1.method(new A());"

Comment: it's print "B" try to run your code.

Comment: Are you sure you executed this same code? Because since you are passing a `C` reference to the method, by default it will consider it for the immediate super class, so 100% its going to print B, unless if you implement it the way wietlol has said.

Comment: We all agree that if I run the example I provided, it prints B. The thing is, in my real life code, it doesn't, and I'm trying to understand why. Thats the point of my question.

Comment: I don't understand. If this doesn't represent your code, then why post it? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, but if I could reproduce the problem, I certainly could find the solution. The sample I provided does represent my code, but I'm obviously missing something. You could argue then that my question is too wide, but I'm running out of ideas, that's why I'm looking for help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

1. class `B` is not the same package than the other classes,
2. `method` is protected, so is visible only through inheritance and for classes *of the same package*,
3. In the `Test` class is in the same package than `A`, so the only `method` visible for `C`, is the one inherited form `A`.

The solution: make `B.method` visible form the `Test` class, either changing it to `public` on `B`, or reimplementing it on `C`:

```
public class C {
    protected void method(C param) {
        super.method(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Constructor of a class have a super() that call its parents constructor by default. you must be see "A" beacause your root class printing "A" in its constructor.
You said your programm display A because is not in same package! this is not true.
Howrever , each class's constructor have a super() that call parent constructor, and you should be know if we not define any constructor for a class it has a default constructor and its may be helpful if we handle this item by define a correct constructor.

Answer (score -2):

Try it again. Its print B

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c1 = new C(), c2 = new C();
        c1.method("");
    }
}

class A {
    protected void method(String param){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected void method(String param){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    // …/…
}
```